# Function with $f'>0$ but not on a $\delta$ neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am looking to find the following:

A function $f$ such that $f'$ exists on an open interval and $f'(c) >0$ for $c$ in this interval but such that there is no $\delta$-nbhood $V_\delta (c)$ of $c$ with $f'(x) > 0$ for $x$ in $V_\delta (c)$.

My idea: $$g_2(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 x^2 \sin ({1 \over x}) & x \neq 0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

But for this function $f'(0) = 0$.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g_2(x)+a\,x$ for appropriate values of $a$.

Comment: Thank you it works for all $a>0$. With $a={1\over 2}$: $$g_2(x) = 
\begin{cases}
{1\over 2}x + x^2 \sin ({1 \over x}) & x \neq 0 \\
{1 \over 2}x & x=0
\end{cases}$$ and for $x_n = {1 \over n \pi}$: $g_2' ({1 \over 2 n \pi }) = - \cos ({2n \pi}) = -1$.